# Can I change the CSS of an extension popup in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I would like to change a appearance of an extension popup in Chrome (namely it's height). Is there a way I can do so?

I'm using Chrome Beta (37) and i'm not the author of the extension.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried fussing through the extension files but couldn't find anything. And this was not a good solution IMO because i would loose it every time the extension upgrades.

Also tried Custom.css in the user stylesheets dir. but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: And where in your question did you specify that it's not an extension you control?

Comment: I've edited the post, clarifying the situation. Thanks Xan.

Comment: Is the popup in a content script?

Comment: anders, i don't understand your question. The extension in cause is Todoist. I want to change the height because i'm not using the default zoom level and i get a double scrollbar on the popup.